# Django - no image where it should be. How can I save image sent through ajax?

Tags: ajax, django

I getting no image path saved in database and no image saved in filesystem. Item istance is saved becaues image is not required.
views.py

```
def add_item(request, item_id):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if request.is_ajax(): 
            form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.user
                title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                content = form.cleaned_data['content']
                image = form.cleaned_data['image']                    
                item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
                item.add_child(user=user, title=title, content=content, image=image)  # add_child() because of using django-treebeard             
                return HttpResponse('')                                
            else:    
                return HttpResponse('')    
        else:        
            return HttpResponse('')
```

jquery:

```
$('#form_for_item').live('submit', function(){
    var data = $("#form_for_item").serialize();
    var url = '/something/add_item/' + $('#form_for_item').attr('name') + '/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            $('#my_form').children().remove();
        }
    });
    return false;  
});
```

I try also form `image` give to my `add_item(request, item_id)` function add this lines:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
    image = SimpleUploadedFile(request.META['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'],request.raw_post_data)
```

but didn't help.
How can I save image sent through ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the issues may be that a normal jQuery AJAX request doesn't send the form data with content-type `multipart/form-data`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) for more information on how to send form data via AJAX with jQuery.

This solution does not seem to be 100% cross-browser compatible. A workaround could be displaying the form in an iframe and then using jQuery to submit the form when it should be saved.

Comment: Too complicated for me. I resign from `image`, but thanks form good wish.